# Periodic Function with Integral

Tags: integration

Problem:

> $f(x)$ is a continuous function, and it is periodic with period $T$. For any $a<b$, prove that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf(nx)dx=\frac{b-a}{T}\int_0^Tf(x)dx$$

I tried substituting $nx=t$, but it gave me $\frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(t)dt$, and I don't know what to do. Can anyone give me hints to solve this? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Roughly speaking, there are about $n(b-a)/T$ periods between $na$ and $nb$.

Comment: @JoeyZou Looking at the problem gives me that intuitively but I don't understand why there would be $n(b-a)/T$ periods between those two numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start is exactly right.  Now note that the integral $\int_{na}^{nb}f(t)dt$ covers some number of full periods of the periodic function (about $n(b-a)/T$ of them, give or take one), plus some extra stuff (whose absolute area can't be more than $TB$, if $B$ is a bound on the absolute value of $f$ -- which must exist, since $f$ is continuous).  Can you prove that the "extra stuff" and the "give or take one" don't contribute in the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Sorry, I think your hint is great but I still don't know how I should proceed.

Comment: May I ask for a full answer??